# List the file permissions of only the current directory

Tags: bash, directory

```
ls -la .
```

will show this in it:

```
insgesamt 1312
drwxrwxr-x  6 ruben rubo77   4096 Feb 23 06:20 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 ruben rubo77   4096 Feb  6 21:48 ..
...
```

But it will show the whole content of the folder too.

I could narrow the output with `head` and `tail`:

```
ls -la .|head -n 2|tail -n 1
```

But isn't there an option in `ls` to show only the current directory you are in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No argument to `ls` necessary, the `-d` option alone together with `-l` will do

```
ls -ld
```

Comment: @JMCF125 I closed because **after I answered** it became clear that the post was a duplicate closed. You don't seem to understand the [se] system.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in the man page:

> -d, --directory
>                 list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

so it is:

```
ls -lad .
```

Comment: If you want an option to select the current directory, then you don't have to specify it as an argument. `ls -ld` will do. The `-a` is unnecessary as well.